# AWS Sqs ReceiveMessage is not as fast as SendMessage

Tags: amazon-web-services, sendmessage, amazon-sqs

I have first web service which is used to send messages into the aws sqs, this web service is deployed on a separate ec2 instance. Web service is running under IIS 8. This web service is able to handle 500 requests per second from two machines meaning 1000 requests per second. It can handle more requests.

I have second web service deployed on another ec2 instance of the same power/configuration. This web service will be used to process the messages stored in the Sqs. For testing purpose currently, I am only receiving the message from Sqs and just deleting that.

I have a aws Sns service which tells the second web service that a message has come in the sqs, go and receive that message to process.

But I observe that my second web service is not as fast as my first web service, every time I run the test, messages are left in the sqs, but ideally no message should remain in the sqs.

Please guide me what are the possible reasons of this and area on which I should focus.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The receiver has double the work to do since it both receives and deletes the message which is done in two separate calls. You may need double the instances to process the sent messages if you have high volume.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but I don't have as high volume for right now, as I mentioned there are only 1000 requests per seconds are coming. Even I have observed processor is not able to handle 500 requests per sec.

Answer (score 0):

How many messages are you receiving at once?   I highly recommend setting the `MaxNumberOfMessages` to 10 and then using `DeleteMessageBatch` with batches of 10.   Not only will this greatly increase throughput, it will cut your SQS bill in by about 60%.

Also, I'm confused about the SNS topic.  There is no need to have an SNS topic tell the other web service that a message exists.  If every message generates a publish to that topic, then you are adding a lot of extra work and expense.  Instead you should use long polling and set the `WaitTimeSeconds` to 20 and just always be calling SQS.   Even if you get 0 messages for a month 2 servers constantly long polling will be well within the free tier.  If you are above the free tier, the total cost of 2 servers constantly long polling an SQS queue is $0.13/month